# GraphQL + SpringBoot: How to hide certain fields from request in response

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I created a graphql schema

```
type Query {
  vehicle(id: String): Vehicle
}
type Vehicle {
  producer: String
  color: String
  engine: String
  year: String
  price: Float
}
```

and received a request

```
query 
 {
   vehicle(id: "123") {
       producer
       color
       price
   }
}
```

But I wanted the response to contain `producer` and `color` only, so `price` is excluded.

Is it possible to do this with Graphql in Springboot? If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: In GraphQL you always return what the client asks for. If you don't want that field to be requested, just remove it from your schema.

Comment: restrict access for field to admins - not admin, return null